# Exchange limit in distribution and pointwise limit

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ denote a sequence of random variables with the following properties.

1. Each $X_n$ is a function of a parameter $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with the property

$$\lim_{c\to\infty}X_n(c)=Y_n,$$

$~~~~~~$ i.e., each $X_n$ converges pointwise to a random variable $Y_n$.

2. In addition, $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to the random variable $X$, i.e., for all $c$

$$X_n(c)\stackrel{d}{\to}X ~~~~~~~~~~\text{as}~~~~~~n\to\infty.$$

$Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n(c)$ be the deterministic random variable $X_n(c) = \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{1+|c|}\right)^n}$. Then $\lim_{c\to\infty}X_n(c) = 1 = Y_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(c) = 0$. But $1$ does not converge to $0$ in distribution.

Comment: Thanks. Are you a aware of any (non-trivial) conditions for $X_n$ such that the statement is true?

Comment: Uniform convergence is probably enough.